# Using htaccess to re-write all possible urls in a MVC style web app?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a Laravel style MVC webapp. Not written in Laravel, but similar concept.

On my dev box, my webapp lived in its own "domain" with the `/public` folder being the document root.

**Folder Structure**

```
MyProject
 | 
 +-- App
 |  |  
 |  +-- Models
 |  |  
 |  +-- Views
 |  |  
 |  +-- Controllers
 |    
 +-- public (doc root)
    |  
    +-- htaccess
    +-- index.php
```

I used this `.htaccess` file to route all the traffic through the index.php file that lived in public folder.

*htaccess*

```
# Remove the question mark from the request but maintain the query string
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

So when you visited http://myinternalproject.com, you could use the webapp fine.

Now, for production, I have to move the project and all of its files to its own folder within our company domain. It **cannot** be a subdomain as per the Administrator.(Which would fix all my problems.)

So it has to be accessed via `www.mydomain.com/apps/myproject/`.

Navigating to: `www.mydomain.com/apps/myproject/public` works fine and the site shows up.

Navigating beyond the "home page" causes all the links to go to: `www.mydomain.com/{controller}/{action}` instead of living in the new sub-folder.

**Is there a way to rewrite all the links in my app to automatically go to  `/apps/myproject/public`  (since that is where the index.php lives) without going through every possible link and prefixing `/apps/myproject/public`?**

I tried variations on appending the new folder structure to the `htaccess`, but can't get it to work.

```
RewriteBase /apps/myproject/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /apps/myproject/public/^(.*)$ /apps/myproject/public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?xyz.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?xyz.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

More about this [here](http://sauravkc.com.np/blog/laravel-in-shared-hosting)

Comment: Maybe I am not plugging in the right data, but I can't get this to work. I keep getting the 500 error.

Comment: interchange sub-directory with your directory path

Comment: Having changed my sub-directory pattern, I can get to the index.php file in `www.mydomain.com/apps/myproject/public/` but non of the URL's are being re-written to append the `app/myproject/`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this additional rule in your document root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* apps/myproject/public/$0 [L]
```

Then you should keep this rule inside `/apps/myproject/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apps/myproject/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [L,QSA]
```